# Remove slash from data and create new field in select query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am using SQL SERVER for database related operation in my application.

I have created one view that contains following data:

[image]

I want one new field with this view and that field should contains the same data as you can see in **Size** column in the above view.

But I have to remove coming slash from that data.

Is there any query or function to remove slash from the data in SQL SERVER?

Comment: Check out `replace()`

Comment: @Raj Ohh yes it's running. thanks Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use SQL replace function to replace single character

example:

```
select Replenter code hereace(ColumnName, '/', '') as NewColumnName,* from  TableName
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this in Query:

```
declare @sam varchar(50);
set @sam= 'this/is/sample';

select replace(@sam,'/','');
```

Answer (score 3):

Just select the columns you need from the view, but use `REPLACE()` on the `Size` column to remove the forward slash:

```
SELECT [SizePropId],
       [VendorId],
       [VendorName],
       [ModelId],
       [Model],
       [SizeId],
       REPLACE([Size], '/', ''), AS [Size]
       [ProductCode],
       [CategoryId],
       [LoadIndex_Spec],
       [RunFlate],
       [ListPrice]
FROM yourView
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such help